# how to handle cookies for okhttpclient requests

Tags: android, cookies, session-cookies, okhttp

I am sending a request to a website's webpage's url using OkHttpClient and storing the cookie it gives by the following method which I got from stackoverflow only.

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
ClearableCookieJar cookieJar = new PersistentCookieJar(new SetCookieCache(), new SharedPrefsCookiePersistor(this));
```

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cookieJar(cookieJar)
                .build();
```

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("www.example.com/homePage")
                .addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0")
                .build();
```

It is necessary to store the cookie otherwise the website redirects the request to a timeout page.

Then, I see the html of the page to check whether I reached the correct URL.

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                textView.setText("Failed to get response");
            }
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    //String myResponse contains the html of the webpage 
                    final String myResponse = response.body().string();
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textView.setText(myResponse);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Now, I make another Request variable in a similar fashion to the URL "www.example.com/loginPage" and try to see the html but it redirects me to the timeout page because the request is made without sending the cookie which I got from the homePage.

So, in short, how can I get a cookie from "www.example.com/cookieProviderPage" and store it and then use that cookie for all further requests to all pages of that website. Pages of that website have different urls like "www.example.com/cookieRequiredPage1", "www.example.com/cookieRequiredPage2" etc.

P.S. - I have checked many stackoverflow questions related to cookies but I am unable to implement the them specifically to my case.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies added with Command

```
new OkHttpClient.Builder()
  .cookieJar(cookieJar)
```

are loaded depending on the `CookieJar.loadForRequest` method. You must check, how your implementation of the interface `CookieJar` implemented the `loadForRequest` method. If cookies are just loaded for exact the same url the cookies originally come from, you have the error. 
If the cookies come from "www.example.com/cookieProviderPage" and you want to supply the cookies for the request "www.example.com/loginPage", your `CookieJar` implementation may only supply the cookies to requests with the url "www.example.com/cookieProviderPage".
This is for example the case, if `Cookie.matches` is used to the get the cookies for the request. `Cookie.matches` compares domain name and path of the url.